# How to sort list by dictionary value?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an array with dictionaries, every dictionary have the same structure.
How to sort by a specific key from dictionary?

### Example

I want to order by *rating*

```
[
{'url': 'http://www.example.com', 'rating': 5.67, 'count': 11, 'language': 'EN'}, 
{ .. },
...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could supply the `key` argument to [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted). If `l` is your list:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda d:d['rating'])
```

Add `reverse=True` if you want to reverse the ordering (i.e. sort from high rating to low).

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [
    {'url': 'http://www.example.com', 'rating': 5.67, 'count': 11, 'language': 'EN'}, 
    { .. },
    ...
]

sorted(l, key=lambda i: i['rating'])
```